# Búsqueda Binaria, Encontrar en cuantos intervalos esta contenido un punto

Tags: python

Estoy intentando crear un preprocesamiento en tiempo `O(nlogn)` tal que, dado un punto sobre el eje OX, me permita encontrar, en tiempo, `O(logn)` a cuantos intervalos pertenece.

Preprocesamiento: He pensado ordenar la lista mediante el algoritmo de quicksort

Algoritmo: He pensado en realizar una búsqueda binaria pero no me termina de funcionar

```
#O(logn)
def algoritmo(inter,i,j,punto):
    if i == j:
        res = -1
    else:
        p = int((i + j) / 2)
        if punto == inter[p][0]:
            res = [inter[p][0],inter[p][1]]
        elif punto <= inter[p][0]:
            res = algoritmo(inter,i,p,punto)
        else:
            res = algoritmo(inter,p,j,punto)
    return res
```

¿Alguna recomendación? ¿Otra manera de hacerlo?

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Esta seria otra forma de hacerlo.

Para hacer la búsqueda binaria, necesitas la lista (Siempre ordenada de menor a mayor), una variable que va a ser el elemento de la mitad de la lista, puedes hacerlo iterativo para que sea mas fácil de verlo,pero primero debes tener en cuenta una 2 cosas:

> **1) Cuando va a terminar mi programa?**

Serian 2 condiciones si la longitud de mi lista es de 1 elemento ó si el elemento buscado se encuentra en la lista y ya lo encontré.

> **2) Que va a hacer mi programa si no aun no encuentra el numero buscado?**

Inmediatamente va evaluar si el numero buscado es mayor al elemento de la mitad o si es menor; si es mayor quiere decir que los elementos que están a su izquierda no me van a servir porque sencillamente son menores entonces los podemos ignorar, sino es porque los elementos de la derecha son mas grandes que el numero que busco, por lo que lo que esta a la derecha lo puedo eliminar.

> **Es este el pensamiento correcto?**

Ahí muchas formas de hacer la búsqueda binaria; esta es sola una forma de muchas que existen ademas es una forma que yo implemente.

> **Entonces como seria el codigo?**

Ya planteamos uno de los pensamientos adecuados para hacer este problema, entonces esta forma es adecuada solo que esta involucrada la lista que va a ser modificada, este algoritmo es de complejidad ***O(Log(n))***.

```
from sys import stdin
def Busqueda_binaria_con_ciclo():

    print('Ingrese una lista cualquiera:')
    b=[int(z) for z in stdin.readline().strip().split()]
    c=b
    num_buscado=int(input('Ingrese el numero a buscar: '))
    medio1=b[(len(b)//2)]
    while True:
        if len(b)==1:
            if b[0]!=num_buscado:
                print('No esta')
                break
            else:
                print(b[0])
                break
        if medio1==num_buscado:
            print(medio1,'Elemento encontrado en la posision {}'.format(c.index(medio1)))
            break
        elif medio1>num_buscado:
            b=b[:len(b)//2]
        elif medio1<num_buscado:
            b=b[len(b)//2:]
        medio1=b[(len(b)//2)]

Busqueda_binaria_con_ciclo()
```

Espero haberte ayudado.